# Do I have to install modules for each project?

Tags: module, pycharm, project

I had to install modules again when I started new project on pycharm.

I think it's some kind of path problem but is this normal?

I mean do you guys install modules for each project?

Answer (score 1):

You can use venv. Just make sure that your new project uses that virtual environment, with the pre-installed modules.

Here's the documentation for venv, that will explain basic concepts and how to use it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to create use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (venv) with each project as you then separate your dependencies and, most importantly, it allows you to create and maintain projects that require different versions of the packages (modules) that you wish to use.

Have a read around the use of [requirements.txt](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html) as that will help you to build and maintain the different venvs.  You want to try to avoid installing packages globally unless you really need to.